# Обнаружить есть ли часть картинки в другой картинке

Tags: python-3.6

у меня есть фотография куска кнопки, как можно определить есть ли данная кнопка на другой фотографии? Пытался с помощью получения всех пикселей куска кнопки, а затем сверять есть ли список этих пикселей в той картинке, но все безуспешно, может есть какой-то вариант?

[image: Кнопка]

[image: Фотография с кнопкой]

Comment: @Kromster отредактировал

Comment: А кнопка попиксельно одинаковая, или имеет переливы и прочие усложнения задачи?

Comment: Также скажите, что вы пробовали конкретно и почему безуспешно?

Comment: @Kromster кнопка одинаковая всегда, разве что кол-во 238 может менятся но это уже мелочь, я поменяю лишь на иконку желтенькую.

Comment: @Kromster с помощью list(image.getdata()) получал список всех пикселей фотографий, и таким же способ на другой фотографии где есть кнопка, далее сверях эти 2 списка, есть ли во 2 списке все значения первого. Но результат всегда был ложью.

Comment: @Michael, это браузерная игра или десктопная?

Comment: @gil9red, нет это игра запущена в андроид эмуляторе MEMU

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно попробовать сделать скрин, через `opencv` найти ту кнопку, например по ее форме, а после кликнуть по расположению кнопки.

В качестве основы скрипта взял пример [поиска книг](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/tree/39fbdcb595f6a210e3ae851e3fcc5dd74d12da55/opencv__examples/Finding%20books%20in%20images), немного его модифицировал и получил расположение кнопки. Я не особо работал с opencv :)

А так, для работы нужно:

1. Загрузить картинку (скриншот можно сделать, например, через `PIL` или `pyautogui.screenshot()`)
2. Сделать предобработку, чтобы убрать лишнее
3. Сделать поиск контуров
4. Фильтрация контуров, например по количеству вершин и размеру

Пример:

```
# pip install opencv-python
import cv2

# Загрузка изображения
image = cv2.imread("img.jpg")
cv2.imshow('image', image)

# Черно-белое изображение
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# Размытие
gray = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (3, 3), 0)
# cv2.imshow('gray', gray)

# Распознавание контуров
edged = cv2.Canny(gray, 10, 250)
# cv2.imshow('edged', edged)

# Закрытие открытых контуров
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (7, 7))
closed = cv2.morphologyEx(edged, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)
# cv2.imshow('closed', closed)

# Нахождение контуров в изображении
contours, _ = cv2.findContours(closed, cv2.RETR_LIST, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
total = 0

image_result = image.copy()

# Перебор контуров
for c in contours:
    # Аппроксимирование (сглаживание) контура
    peri = cv2.arcLength(c, True)
    approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(c, 0.05 * peri, True)

    # Если у контура 6 вершины, предполагаем, что это нужная нам кнопка
    if len(approx) != 6:
        continue

    # Дополнительно фильтруем по размеру
    rect = cv2.boundingRect(c)
    width, height = rect[2:]

    # Нужно подбирать
    if height != 50 and width != 169:
        continue

    print(f'Кнопка: {rect}')

    cv2.drawContours(image_result, [approx], -1, (0, 0, 255), 4)
    total += 1

print(f"На картинке найдено: {total}")
cv2.imwrite("output.jpg", image_result)
cv2.imshow('image_result', image_result)

cv2.waitKey()
```

---

Немного картинок.

Например, картинка из вопроса после обработки становится такой (строка `cv2.imshow('closed', closed)`):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А после пунктов **3.** и **4.**, скрипт определил расположение кнопки в `(196, 454, 169, 50)` (т.е. по `x`, `y`, `width`, `height`) и рисования найденного контура:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А как можно прочитать сделанный скриншот с помощью cv, его обязательно нужно сохранять и потом открывать? Или с буфер обмена можно прочесть?

Comment: @Michael, скриншот в файл не обязательно сохранять. Скриншот можно сделать так: https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2018/01/01/taking-screenshots-with-opencv-and-python/ . В гугле это легко находится: `python opencv screenshot`

Comment: https://sun9-32.userapi.com/c855616/v855616969/250d4b/PESvs1ZGD08.jpg

Такая проблема что теперь он реагирует и на серые кнопки которые появляются после закрытия данного окошка с кнопкой, можно ли как-то это обходить?

Comment: @Michael, фильтруйте в том цикле, например по позиции в `y`, например оставляя те контуры, что находятся примерно по середине. Я как то делал бота для игры, там было много проверок -- размер, положение, цвет и т.п.: https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/39fbdcb595f6a210e3ae851e3fcc5dd74d12da55/Bot%20Buff%20Knight%20Advanced/main.py#L24